# Can I install SPIFFS for Wemos D1 Mini Lite (ESP8285 chip) to use JS, HTML and CSS files as a stand alone webserver

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, webserver

I am looking to create a standalone webserver using the Wemos D1 Mini Lite (this is the only wifi microcontroller I have and cant afford a different one atm).

I know SPIFFS works with ESP32 chips, but can I use it with ESP8285 chips?

Looking to have HTML and CSS for the webserver, with JS scripts to run functions (At the moment only functionality is turning LEDs off and on), all uploaded to the Wemos and run from that.

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./theme.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "mainDiv border" > 
        <div class = "headingDiv border">
            <h3 id = "Header"> LED ON AND OFF </h3> 
        </div>
        <div class = "checkmarkDiv border">
            <div class = "row">
                <label for ="colour_red">RED LED</label>
                <input type = "checkbox" id = "colour_red">
            </div>
            <div class = "row">
                <label for ="colour_yellow">YELLOW LED</label>
                <input type = "checkbox" id = "colour_yellow">
            </div>
            <div class = "row">
                <label for ="colour_green">GREEN LED</label>
                <input type = "checkbox" id = "colour_green">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "buttonDiv border">
            <button class = "button-primary" id = "button_ToggleLED"> Turn LED: ON </button>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
<script src = "./mainJS.js"></script>
</html>
```

**JS CODE**

```
const button_LED = document.getElementById(  "button_ToggleLED" )
const cb_red = document.getElementById ( "colour_red" )
const cb_yellow = document.getElementById( "colour_yellow" )
const cb_green = document.getElementById( "colour_green" )

let clickCheck = false

button_LED.addEventListener( "click", (event) => {
    //consoleLEDStatus()
    if (clickCheck) {
        button_LED.innerHTML = "Turn LED: ON"
        turnOFFLED()
    }   
    else if (!clickCheck) {
        button_LED.innerHTML = "Turn LED: OFF"
        turnONLED()
    }
    clickCheck = !clickCheck
})

//  A quick function you can run to check in dev console the status of LED
function consoleLEDStatus() {
    console.log(`LED Status:
       RED:        ${cb_red.checked}
       YELLOW:     ${cb_yellow.checked}
       GREEN:      ${cb_green.checked}`)
}

function turnOFFLED() {
    //  Insert function to turn off LED
}

function turnONLED() {
    //  Insert function to turn on LED
}
```

**CSS CODE**

```
/* Test class for checking Div borders. Uncomment to see them*/
/*
.border{
    border: black 2px solid;
}
*/

.mainDiv{
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.checkmarkDiv{
    padding: 10px;
}

.buttonDiv{
    padding: 10px;
}

.headingDiv{
    padding: 10px;
}

#Header{

}

#button_ToggleLED{
    width: 200px;
    float: center;
}
```

Comment: SPIFFS has been replaced with LittleFS (Little File System) and it works on EPS8266, See [LittleFS](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/LittleFS).

Comment: The code example for using LittleFS to serve webpage can be found at [FSBrowser](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/FSBrowser) example. It is a quite comprehensive example, you probably only need to implement part of it.

Comment: How can i tick this off an an answer?

Comment: Okay, I added it as an answer instead of comment. You can tick it to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPIFFS has been replaced with LittleFS (Little File System) and it works on EPS8266, See [LittleFS](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/LittleFS) for more details.

The code example for using LittleFS to serve webpage can be found at [FSBrowser](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/FSBrowser) example. It is a quite comprehensive example, you probably only need to implement part of it.